# Travel from Europe to Asia tickets

Tags: air-travel, japan, south-korea

my family will be visiting me in Japan soon and we plan to make a trip to South Korea too. So they would be coming from France to Japan, then from Japan to Korea, then Korea to Japan and from Japan back to France.

So we would like to take a ticket from Osaka (Japan) to Seoul (Korea) then from Seoul to Tokyo (Japan). The problem is that when booking a flight from Osaka to Seoul, some companies ask that a return ticket is taken or we might be denied access to the flight. Although these companies do no block you from buying a one way ticket.

Is it okay to book a one way ticket from Osaka to Seoul then another one way ticket from Seoul to Tokyo on another company ? Or do they need the return trip to be on same ticket ?

Also, from what I get, you don't need to get a visa if you stay less than 90 days in Japan and Korea. But is there going to be a visa problem with leaving Japan to Korea and coming back soon after ?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

For your second question, no, there shouldn't be a problem in re-entering Japan. Even in the unlikely event that you are questioned, you have your ticket back to France to show that your goal is not to stay for another 90 days.

It's better to ask one question per question, by the way...

Answer (score 1):

For your Korea trip, as long as you both one way tickets before you go, then you will have no problem proving your intended departure from Korea.  The outbound flight does not have to be on the same airline nor to the same destination.

Japan won't care if your family enters, goes to Korea and then returns.  They would likely only be worried if you started doing the full visa free stay, left for day, did another full stay, etc several times in a row.